# How to make the picture and text go in a row

Tags: html, css, jinja2

I need the default picture and text to go in a row, but when the screen resolution decreased, the text moved under the picture

```html
<div style="background-color:#474747;">
    <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
    <a href="" style="margin-left:20px;">
        <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="font-size:20px; color:white;">
            {{ article.view }} {{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}
        </i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could provide a minimal reproducible example. Broken HTML with data binding brackets isn't a great start.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what its supposed to look like but you should fix your broken code then use CSS to tell all your block-level elements to be inline-block instead. Something like:

```css
.allinline {
  background-color: #474747;
}

.allinline * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="allinline">
  <p><img src="imgurlhere" /></p>
  <a href="" style="margin-left:20px;">
    <h3>article.title</h3>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="font-size:20px; color:white; ">article.date</i> </a>
</div>
```

Better yet, refactor your html into something a little more semantic and then use flexbox to achieve your desired layout. (Again, I'm guessing a bit at what you want it to look like)

```css
.linkblock {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #474747;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.linkblock img {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.linkblock em {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="linkblock">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" />
  <strong>article.title</strong> <em class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">article.date</em>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent children elements from breaking into diffrent lines, set `white-space:nowrap` on parent.

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap;background-color:#474747;">
    <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
    <a href="" style="margin-left:20px;">
        <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" style="font-size:20px; color:white;">
            {{ article.view }} {{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}
        </i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Note: block elements always take 100% of width. You have also to update that paragraph and h1 to be `inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flex box while creating responsive Web designs.
Reference: - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Summary: In the example below, i have a parent element with display flex,and i have defined two child elements. One child will have image and the other will have text. I have defined on parent element to wrap the child elements if there is no space left using flex-wrap property.

```
 <div class="parent">    
  <div class="flex-1 child-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720
C/O https://placeholder.com/"/>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 child-text">
    Some Dummy Text
  </div>
</div>

body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-1{
  flex: 1;
}
.child-text{
  whitespace: nowrap;
}
```